# Euler-fermat theorem with huge exponents

Tags: elementary-number-theory

we have just been taught the Euler-Fermat theorem and in the classwork the usual exercises are like *"find the last $n$ digits of $a^{a^{b^{...^{z}}}}$ where $a,b,...,z$ are integers"*. The thing is that you cannot use pocket calculators - and, besides, it wouldn't be so useful with such huge nubers.

Obviously the last $n$ digits of a number are the results of that number $mod 10^n$; then $\phi\left(10^n\right)=4*10^{n-1}$, and voilà, if $a$ is relatively prime to 10, you can use the Theorem.

However, the problem is: how do you manage such huge exponents? Already finding the last two digits in the case of 7^14^21 or 9^9^9^9 is a nightmare. Where is my mistake?

Thanks

Comment: You iterate the procedure. You need to find $b^{c^{\dotsc^z}}\pmod{\varphi(10^n)}$, then, supposing $b$ is coprime, you need $c^{d^{\dotsc^z}} \pmod{\varphi(\varphi(n))}$ ... and so on, until you get something manageable.

Comment: Let's say I have to find the last two digits of 7^14^21. In this case, I have $b=14$, $c=21$; and $n=2$. So I should find $14^{21} mod  \phi(100)$ - whose value I do not know given the exponent - and $21 mod \phi(2)=21$. Ok, then how do I proceed?

Comment: Okay, you need $14^{21}\pmod{40}$. Now, $14$ is not coprime to $40$, hence you need to consider $14^{21}\pmod{8}$ and $14^{21}\pmod{5}$ separately ($40 = 2^3\cdot 5$), and assemble the results with the Chinese remainder theorem (or another method). Of course $14^{21} = 2^{21}\cdot 7^{21}\equiv 0 \pmod{2^3}$. And $14^{21} \equiv 4^{21} \equiv 4 \pmod{5}$, since $4^2\equiv 1 \pmod{5}$. The solution to $x\equiv 0 \pmod{2^3}$ and $x\equiv 4 \pmod{5}$ is $x\equiv 24 \pmod{40}$, thus $14^{21}\equiv 24 \pmod{40}$, and you need to find $7^{24}\pmod{100}$. You can do that by repeated squaring, or note

Comment: that $7^4 = 2401 \equiv 1 \pmod{100}$, hence $7^{24} = (7^4)^6 \equiv 1^6\equiv 1\pmod{100}$.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel; it is clear. There is only one case that we did not cover, which is the one when the base b is coprime to the exponent. What should I do in that context? suppose it was 7^7^7^7, instead.

Comment: Well, then, to find $7^{7^{7^7}} \pmod{100}$, find the exponent modulo $\varphi(100)$, that is, $7^{7^7}\pmod{40}$. Since $7$ is coprime to $40$, we need to find $7^7\pmod{\varphi(40)}$. As $\varphi(40) = \varphi(2^3)\cdot \varpi(5) = 4\cdot 4 = 16$, we need $7^7\pmod{16}$. But $7^2 = 49 \equiv 1\pmod{16}$, so $7^7 = 7\cdot(7^2)^3 \equiv 7\pmod{16}$. So one level back $7^{7^7} \equiv 7^7 \pmod{40}$. We remember $7^4 = 2401$, and that is $\equiv 1 \pmod{40}$, hence $7^7 \equiv 7^3 = 343 \equiv 23\pmod{40}$. Back again, $7^{7^{7^7}} \equiv 7^{23}\pmod{100}$, and since $7^4\equiv 1\pmod{100}$,

Comment: that is reduced to $7^{7^{7^7}} \equiv 7^3 = 343 \equiv 43\pmod{100}$.

Comment: Still I have a doubt, Daniel - what do I do when the exponent is too low in comparison with the modulus - suppose I have 9^9 mod 100  and, as usual, I cannot use a calculator?

Comment: Then you just exponentiate by squaring, taking the modulus after each step. $9^9 = (9^4)^2\cdot 9$, $9^4 = (9^2)^2 = 81^2 \equiv (-19)^2 \equiv 19^2 \equiv 361 \equiv 61 \pmod{100}$, so $(9^4)^2 \equiv 61^2 = 3721 \equiv 21 \pmod{100}$, $9^9 \equiv (9^4)^2\cdot 9 \equiv 21\cdot 9 = 189 \equiv 89 \pmod{100}$.